# CdkDragAndDrop how to disable dropping – Angular

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

Two element lists. From the first list a user can drag elements to the second one, or he can move elements within the second list. He cannot drag & drop element to the first list.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular 'cdkDropList' for drag and drop. 'cdkDropListEnterPredicate' will disable dropping inside the same list.
Please refer example in this
[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5rtkdm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-disabled-sorting-example.html)

Comment: How can I set up the cdkDropList for the case of image files in the directories which cannot have a fixed number to perform image drag and drop to the particular zone which has been designated as "Canvas" ?